# Angular Reactive Forms in Reusable Child Components: Problem with FormArrays: `formGroupName` must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'am trying to describe the problem on an example ([full example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8knpgm))

If I try to place some parts of reactive-form in the form of simple "formControls" or "formGroups" withing child-components, there are no problems. (See the example on stackblitz above). `FormGroupDirective` works as expected.

But If I try to place a FormArray within a child-component, I get troubles because of:

```html
<div [formGroupName]="i">
  <!--
    Error: formGroupName must be used 
    with a parent formGroup directive.
  -->
<div>
```

The Reactive-Form is a simple form:

```js
  ngOnInit () {
    this.newForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [{value: '4711', disabled: this.idReadOnly}, Validators.required],
      chapter: this.fb.group({
        name: ['Some Chapter', Validators.required]
      }),
      faq: this.fb.array(this.faqArray)
    });
  }
```

As already mentioned above there are no problems with `id` and `chapter`, they are implemented in custom-child-components, like:

```html
<fe-input 
  [controlPath]="['id']"
  placeholder="Child-FormControl ID"
></fe-input>

<my-form-group 
[controlPath]="['chapter', 'name']"
placeholder="Child-FormGroup Chapter"
[required]="true"
>
</my-form-group>
```

In the App on stackblitz you will see the working parts 'ID' and 'Chapter'.

The same approach with `formArray`:

```html
<my-form-array 
[controlPath]="['faq']" 
placeholder="Child-FormArray FAQ"
[required]="true"
></my-form-array>
```

should work as expected to my mind but the part `<div [formGroupName]="i">` causes only within a child-component the already mentioned error above:

```
Error: formGroupName must be used 
with a parent formGroup directive.
```

If I use that in the original file (where is the reactive form is defined), it works without problems.

I'm confused, maybe I just overlook a simple problem? Can someone help me? The whole example is available online here: ( [>> stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8knpgm))

**UPDATE 1:**

I've integrated the solution from @yurzui with

```html
viewProviders: [{ 
  provide: ControlContainer, 
  useExisting: FormGroupDirective 
}]
```

and the error "`Error: formGroupName must be used..`" is disappeared. Afterwards, I've integrated the custom component for formArray fields and they cannot get the control value. I think I'm close to the solution. That's the custom component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'fe-input',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [formControl]="control"
        [required]="required"
      />
      <mat-error>
        This is a required field!
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
  styles: [

  ]
})
export class FormElementInputComponent implements OnInit {
  // Values to be set:
  @Input() controlPath: any;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() controlValue: any;
  @Input() required = false;

  // That's the reuseable control
  control: FormControl;

  constructor(private fgd: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.fgd.control.get(
      this.controlPath
    ) as FormControl;
  }
}
```

And finally that's the template part of `my-form-array`:

```html
 template: `
  <div fxLayout="column">
    <div *ngFor="let c of control.controls; index as i">

      <div [formGroupName]="i">

        <fe-input 
        [controlPath]="q"
        placeholder="Question"
        [required]="required"
      ></fe-input>

      <fe-input 
        [controlPath]="a"
        placeholder="Answer"
        [required]="required"
      ></fe-input>
      <div>

    </div>
  </div>
  `,
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4x46nm?file=src/app/my-form-array.component.ts

Comment: thank you @yurzui, I don't know, why I need that, but I've updated stickblitz and the error (..must be used..) is disappeared. Afterwards, I've integrated the custom components for input fields  but the custom components still does not get the control value. Would you see that? Many thanks,.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8knpgm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your FormArray is a FormArray of FormControls who get as value an Object, NOT a FormArray of FormGroup. You must change when create the form like

```
this.newForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [{value: '4711', disabled: this.idReadOnly}, Validators.required],
  chapter: this.fb.group({
    name: ['Some Chapter', Validators.required]
  }),
  faq: this.fb.array(this.faqArray.map(x=>this.fb.group({
    q:x.q,
    a:x.a
  })))
});
```

Second, you can use the "other way" to work with FormArray of FormGroup that it's not use [formGroupName="i"] else [formGroup]="control". yes

```
<!--remove this that not work
<div *ngFor="let c of control.controls; index as i">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
           ....
      <div>
</div>
-->
<!--use [formGroup] -->
<div  *ngFor="let c of control.controls; index as i">
    <div [formGroup]="c">
          ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Well, inside the formGroup you need your fe-input [controlPath]="'q'" and [controlPath]="'a'"

I remove the form-group because it's wrong too, try use [formGroup] and use viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]

You see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-81d6jh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-form-array.component.ts)

**Update** if we mark the formArray using

```
<my-form-array 
[controlPath]="['faq','a','q']"
placeholder="Child-FormArray FAQ"
[required]="true"
></my-form-array>
```

We can change our my-form-array so, in ngOnInit

```
this.control = this.fgd.control.get(
      this.controlPath[0]
    ) as FormArray;
```

And the .html

```
   <div *ngFor="let c of control.controls; index as i">
      <div [formGroup]="c">
       <fe-input *ngFor="let fields of controlPath.slice(1)"
        [controlPath]="fields"
        placeholder="Question"
        [required]="required"
      ></fe-input>
    </div>
```

[the re-forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxkzds?file=src/app/my-form-array.component.ts)

Comment: I update my answer to improve the my-form-array, good luck with the FormGroup

Comment: yes indeed, it works and I have to understand why :)

Comment: Oh, happy too early; it does not work completely: only answers are repeated without the questions: '(

Comment: Sorry, I updated in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpzcvk?file=src/app/app.component.html -I changed the order, now is [controlPath]="['faq','q','a']", and [placeholder]="['Question','Answer']", so we can put in the .html of myfom-array-component [placeHolder]="placeholder[j]" -j the index of the inner *ngFor

Comment: it is OK, I've found by the way an easier solution too, but it is OK, thank you,..

Answer (score 0):

so in your child component you have to use `formArrayName="faq"` which you will be getting from parent component using `FormGroupDirective` and in child component's viewProviders array you have to use `useExisting` like this

```
viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }
  ]
```

in your html

```
<div formArrayName="faq" *ngFor="let fa of faq['controls']; let faqIndex = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="faqIndex">
// here goes your code
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that already: Apart from not working,`my-form-array` would not be reusable. Maybe can you fork it and try? The reusability is very important, it should work with any FormArray not just only with "faq".