# Angular FormGroupArray element passed to component

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have an angular form which contains a form group array that I want to pass to a child component.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  email: [''],
  installations: this.fb.array([]),
  ...
```

and my initialiser creates the first item in the array:

```
get installations(){
  return this.myForm.get('installations') as FormArray;
}

addInstallation(){
  this.installations.push(
    this.fb.group({
      item1: [''],
      item2: ['']
}
```

and I iterate of the installations in my html

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let inst of installations.controls; let i = index">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>Installation {{ i + 1 }}</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <app-installation-details [formGroupName]="i"></app-installation-details>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

so I want my app-installation-details child component to pick up the individual installation:

```
public installationDetailsFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.installationDetailsFormGroup = <FormGroup>this.controlContainer.control;
}
```

but the console always complains that:

```
Cannot find control with name: '0'
```

and it says the same thing if I change the item passed:

```
 <app-installation-details [formGroupName]="inst"></app-installation-details>
```

errors with

```
 Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]'
```

Comment: I think, you should be passing `[formControlName]="inst"` or if you pass formGroup `[formGroupName]="myForm"`, you need to make changes accordingly in child component.

Comment: Is app-installation-details a controlValueAccesor component? What does it look like?

Comment: `i` is your index, `inst` is your `FormGroup`. `[formGroupName]` expects a name (string) of the form group. Pass the `inst` via `@Input`.

Comment: would that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842459/angular-reactive-forms-in-reusable-child-components-problem-with-formarrays-f/56847139#56847139 or that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270564/dividing-a-form-into-multiple-components-with-validation